# Select all records in which the sum of values are equal to a specific value

Tags: mysql

I have a `products` table that looks like this *(the other fields are hidden for simplicity)*

```
id | price
----------
1  |  199
2  |  50
3  |  320
4  |  120
```

I'm trying to create a query that selects all products in which values are equal to or less than a specific value, for example:

A customer wants to spend $600 at max, the first 3 products of the example should be returned (**199+50+320 = 569**)

I tried with the query below but got no success

```
select * from products group by id having sum(price) <= 600
```

Comment: Caution:  In an extreme case, one can devise a list of only 40 items where the resultset would have over a _trillion_ combinations!  (Simply have the max be greater than the sum of the individual prices.  That leads to 2^40-1 result rows.)

Comment: Instead of "... selects all products in which ..." do you mean "... selects every combination of products in which ..." or " "... selects some combination of products in which ..." or "... that comes closest to 600".  Please tighten up the Question.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm trying to create a query that selects all products in which values
> are equal to or less than a specific value

We need to create a cumulative sum for this case.

```
select id,
       price
from ( SELECT id,
              price,
              SUM(price) OVER(ORDER BY id asc ) AS cumulative_sum
       FROM products
     ) cum_sum
where cumulative_sum <=600;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/8A46Gmcy

*Note*, above cumulative sum is ordered by the id which means it will test the first products.

If id 1 is equal to 601 query will return empty set.

You can change the order of the cumulative SUM based on your needs.

```
 SUM(price) OVER(ORDER BY price asc ) AS cumulative_sum  ---will start from the lowest price to max
```

**Edit** A more suitable answer/question would be finding every possible combination of the values which the sum is less than 600.

```
with recursive cte as ( 
    select id as max_id,
           price,
           cast(id as char(255))  as possible_combination 
           from products
  union all
    select p.id as max_id,
           c.price + p.price as price,
           cast(concat(c.possible_combination ,',' , p.id) as char(255))  as possible_combination
   from cte c
   inner join products p on p.id > c.max_id                       
)
select possible_combination,price
from cte
where price <= 600 ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/IaqXBqzi

Comment: If the goal is to find _some combination_ of items that add up to under 600, this fails miserably.  It only finds certain _consecutive_ items.

Comment: It seems to return the starting item of a list _that ends with the last_ item.  I see that as a useless goal, so downvoting.  (If you sufficiently rewrite your Answer, I will remove my downvote.)

Comment: @RickJames edited with a solution for every possible combination which I guess would be a proper answer

Comment: @RickJames what do you mean by one combination? It works fine [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/XP-shVLZ). Am I missing something?

Comment: Your recursive CTE seems correct.  I was merely commenting that hardly any combinations are excluded as >600, namely 1,3,4 and 1,2,3,4.  (I wonder what the OP can do with the results.)

Comment: @ErgestBasha why did you add `c.possible_combination not like concat('%,',cast(p.id as char(255)),',%')` in the recursive join clause? It doesn't seem to be affecting the output

Comment: @RishavGhosh to not have dupes , but now that you mentioned and I rechecked, it seems excess.